# Git merge - adds files pulled with no conflicts to next commit

Tags: git

I am trying to pull the latest commit which we will say has 3 different files:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

I run:

```
git pull origin master
```

This pulls down the 3 files above and tells me there is a conflict in file1.txt which I identify using

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

I fix up this conflict and call

```
git add file1.txt
```

However when I call

```
git status -uno
```

It says

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
(use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:
modified:   text1.txt
modified:   text2.txt
new file:   text3.txt

Etc. Etc.
```

Why is it adding text2.txt and text3.txt to my commit? I just pulled these from origin?

(FYI I am scripting all this and simplified it for the sake of the example).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The really short answer is "yes".  But there are a bunch of misconceptions that this simple "yes, they're because you pulled" leaves behind.

#### Long

First, you need to stop thinking in terms of individual files, as `git pull` does not pull *files*.  In fact, it's just a wrapper to run two Git commands.  If you're new to Git, I recommend *avoiding* `git pull`: use the two separate commands, as it will give you a much better idea what's going on, and what to do when one of the two commands fails.

(This is especially important in scripts: avoid user-oriented, high level commands in favor of the machine-oriented or *plumbing* commands.  They are designed for this use, and don't vary their behavior based on each user's personal configuration preferences.  The `git pull` command is *not* a plumbing command, but `git fetch` is, or can be.  The second command we'll look at isn't, but working around that is harder.)

#### `git fetch`

The first of the two commands that `git pull` runs is `git fetch`: for instance, `git pull origin master` runs `git fetch origin master`.  If you run this yourself, you get to leave off the `origin master` entirely here: your Git will, by default, fetch from another Git using the URL stored under the name `origin`.

This step brings over *commits*.  While it's true that commits contain files (so this brings over files), it's best to think about them as the commits that they are.  Each one is a snapshot of *every* file, as it was at the time someone made that commit.

Commits are actually identified by their hash IDs (e.g., `commit b9c30a8...`), and each commit stores the hash ID of its *parent* commit.  This lets Git string together the commits in chains, which always look backwards.  A *branch name* simply contains the ID of the *latest* commit on the branch:

```
... <-commit1  <-commit2  <-commit3   <--branch-name
```

When you first `git clone` some Git repository, you instruct your Git to make a new repository and fill it in from all the commits in some other, existing, Git repository.  Your commits are *the same* as their commits (have the same IDs).  Your Git, meanwhile, remembers where *their* branch names pointed using names like `origin/master`, and makes your own branch name, `master`, point to *the same* commit:

```
...--I--J   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

(One of your branch names gets `HEAD` attached to it so that your Git know which branch you're on.)

As you make new commits, `origin/master`—which is remembering *their*, `origin`'s, master—stays put, but your `master` moves so that it remembers your *latest* commit.  Your new commit remembers the ID of the previous commit:

```
          K   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--I--J   <-- origin/master
```

When you run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`, your Git calls up the other Git again and finds out what commits it has that you don't—commits that are new to you.  Your Git has their Git send those commits over, and then updates your `origin/*` names to remember their latest branch pointers:

```
          K   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--I--J--L   <-- origin/master
```

This is where the second command comes in.

Before we get there, let me add a terminology side note.  When you go to make a new commit, you work on files in your *work-tree*, but then you run `git add somefile.ext`.  This *copies* the file from your work-tree, into what Git calls its *index* or *staging-area*.  The index is perhaps best described as *where you build the next commit you will make*.  It starts out containing a copy of each file from the current commit.  You copy new versions into the index to make them ready to go into the next commit, and files that you don't overwrite *stay* in the index and *also* go into that next commit.  So this is why every commit is a snapshot of *every* file—well, every file that was in the index at that time.

The index takes on an expanded role during a merge, we are about to see.

#### `git merge`

The second command that `git pull` runs is usually either `git merge` or `git rebase`—which one it uses depends on user configuration settings, among other things.  In your particular case it obviously used `git merge`.  In particular it ran `git merge -m "Merge branch 'master' of <url>" <hash-id>`, but when you do this yourself, you can normally just run `git merge` with no arguments.

The merge command has a number of different operating modes.  By default, though, it looks at both your current commit/branch (as remembered by the attached `HEAD`), and the other commit or branch name you supply, or the *upstream* of the current branch.  The *goal* of this operation is to combine any work you did, with any work they—whoever they are—did.  To do this, Git needs to find the first commit that you and they *share*.

Looking at the graph we drew, it's obvious which commit you both started with:

```
          K   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--I--J--L   <-- origin/master
```

The commit you two shared, before you and they went your different ways, was commit `J`.  So now, your Git in effect runs two `git diff` commands:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-J> <hash-of-K>
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-J> <hash-of-L>
```

This diff finds that you modified `file1.txt` or `text1.txt` (whichever it is—I'll go with `text1.txt` here), and that they also modified `text1.txt`.  Perhaps you *didn't* modify `text2.txt`, but they did; and you *didn't* create a new file `text3.txt`, but they did.

Your Git now attempts to *combine* all of these changes, starting with all the files in the merge base itself as the starting-point.  You and they both modified `text1.txt` so your Git tries to combine your changes to that file with their changes to that file.  **This attempt fails,** so Git will soon stop with a merge conflict; but meanwhile, it goes on to combine their changes to `text2.txt` with your lack-of-changes to `text2.txt`.  That's really easy!  It just takes their `text2.txt`.  Then it goes on to combine their new creation of `text3.txt` with your lack-of-creation of `text3.txt`, and that, too, is really easy.

Now your Git stops with the conflict.  It leaves *all three versions* of `text1.txt` in your index / staging-area / cache.  The merge command also leaves, in your work-tree, its own attempt to combine all three versions, with the `<<<<<<<` ... `>>>>>>>` markers in it, so that's a fourth version of the file.

It's your job, at this point, to figure out what the correct combination is.  You can extract all three higher-stage (base, `--ours`, and `--theirs`) versions from the index—that's what `git mergetool` does, for instance—and/or work with Git's attempt to combine them that Git left in the work-tree.  When you're done combining, though, you should:

1. Leave the combined version in the work-tree, under the name `text1.txt`.
2. Run `git add text1.txt`.  This copies the version from the work-tree into the index, *removing* from the index the three higher-stage versions.

Now that there's just one version in the index, which is the correctly-merged one, it's ready to be committed.  Meanwhile, `text2.txt` and `text3.txt` are *also* in the index, in the normal (stage-zero) "ready to be committed" state.  But so are every *other* file.

You see these three files, but not other files, because for those three files, the version in the index, built up and ready for the next commit, *differs from* what's in the current commit.  For every other file in the index, what's in the index is *the same as* what's in the current commit, so `git status` does not report "will be in commit but is the same".

Comment: Excellent answer thanks this really clarified this for me (after reading it multiple times!). Background: We are (new to) using Git for an ERP system with thousands of text files as the source code. With multiple developers working off the same branch the hope was that each commit would clearly show **only** those changes that developer made themselves. But I understand that we will need to think differently in terms of the merged commits rather than examining the individual files in them.